# No errors but output is unexpected

Tags: python

this is my code

```py
for i in range(1,5): 
    print(i for x in range(1,i+1))
```

for this code the output is

> <generator object  at 0x0000025B9C7A9BA0> 
> <generator object  at 0x0000025B9C7A9BA0>
> <generator object  at 0x0000025B9C7A9BA0>
> <generator object  at 0x0000025B9C7A9BA0>

Comment: What do you think should be the output instead? Why?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 4):

you need create `list`.

try this:

```
for i in range(1,5): 
    print([i for x in range(1,i+1)])
```

in short format you can try this:

```
print([i for i in range(1,5) for x in range(1,i+1)])
```

or

```
list(map((lambda x : print([x for _ in range(1,x+1)])), range(1,5)))
```

or by thanks of @Sujay for run faster you can use `tuple` like below:

```
tuple(map((lambda x : print([x for _ in range(1,x+1)])), range(1,5)))
```

for check runtime i use below code:

```
%timeit tuple(map((lambda x : print([x for _ in range(1,x+1)])), range(1,5)))
# 794 µs ± 86.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit list(map((lambda x : print([x for _ in range(1,x+1)])), range(1,5)))
# 806 µs ± 150 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: You should probably use ```tuple``` instead of list because it is less expensive and faster: ```tuple(i for x in range(1,i+1))```

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```py
i for x in range(1,i+1)
```

that is a "generator expression" and it results in a "generator" (`<generator object at ...>`), which is an "iterable". Lists are also iterables. A generator's advantage is that it only actually evaluates the element expression (here `i`) when you iterate over it.

You seem to want an actual list though. You can immediately create a list like so:

```py
[i for x in range(1,i+1)]
```

Or in your code:

```py
for i in range(1,5): 
    print([i for x in range(1,i+1)])
```

The expression `[... for ... in ...]` is a "list comprehension". It looks similar to a generator expression, but it creates a list directly, without a generator. List comprehensions came first to Python, then came generator expressions. They have the same syntax inside different braces.

If you have a generator already, you could also turn it into a list:

```py
for i in range(1,5): 
    gen = (i for x in range(1,i+1))
    print(list(gen)) # get all the elements and make a list
```

That generator is then "used up" and has no more elements to give.